# How to disable tooltip placement change in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to disable the change placement functionality in tooltip in bootstrap.To make the tooltip only from the top, anyway. I tried to set the parameter data-placement="top". The element is located at the top, that's just how the element starts to disappear from the screen, the tooltip changes its position to the bottom.

How to make the tooltip always be located only on top?

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ placement: 'top' });
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do that with CSS

```
.tooltip {
  top: -100% !important;  // !important is mandatory if you want to override bootstarp CSS
  bottom: auto !important;
}
```